# Downloading a file from a PHP server via a website

Tags: php, html, file-upload, download

I have physical files which I want users to download on my website. The files are located at:

`C:/xampp/htdocs/myfile/uploads/*`

I need a PHP script which can download files dynamically on click. Let's say I have the following button which when clicked it triggers `magic.php` script.

`<a href="magic.php?file=name"> Download file </a>`

What PHP code do I need in `magic.php` to download the file name I passed in the query parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download link

```
<a href="magic.php?file=<?php echo urlencode($row['name']); ?>">Download</a>
```

magic.php page

```
<?php
$file = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/myfile/uploads/'.urldecode($_GET['file']);

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this: (Correct me if i am wrong)

```
<a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" download="download">
```