# download image from server folder using ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have website which uses ajax for most of cases. I have allowed user to upload image through ajax. When user clicks on a button the image is displayed in modal through an ajax call.

Now, I want to user to begin his download by clicking on image without closing the modal or refreshing. I did tried with href. It works fine but, as I mentioned, I want to keep user on same page with modal open.

The code I have tried untill now is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imgname;
    imgname = '';
    $("#modalimage").click(function(){
        imgname = $("#downloadimg").val();
        downloadImage(imgname);
    })
})
```

```
function downloadImage(imagename){
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "download.php",
            data : { imagename : imagename } ,
            success : function(response){
                alert('success');
            }
    })
}
```

**download.php** code is:

```
if ( isset($_POST['imagename']) ) {
    $filename = $_POST['imagename'];
    $filepath = 'images/'.$filename;
}
echo $filepath;
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
```

The problem here is when ajax make call to download.php it create a response in form of some binary codes and small image codes without initiating the download. Is it possible to download the image by ajax call?

[image: here is the image]

Comment: As far as I understood, do you want to upload an image file through AJAX, right?

Comment: i have already uploaded the image with ajax call.. now i want to download that image by making ajax call

Comment: Okay, so you want your user to be able to download an image file through AJAX, right?

Comment: yes. that is what i'm trying to do but it is creating some characters in download.php

Comment: Please have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668971/uploading-downloading-a-file-to-a-php-server-via-a-website/27669176

Comment: @ Salim Ibrogimov as i mentioned in the question i have tried it,it works but i dont want to redirect page. i have added image and displayed it. i want to initiate download when user clicks on image without redirecting the page.

Comment: I have not shown the redirect code here... I want to download by making ajax ... I think I'm not making my issue clear

Comment: What about, wrapping your image inside a link: <a href="<PATH_TO_IMG>" download><img src="<PATH_TO_IMG>"></a>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling it by ajax place this link:

```
<a href="download.php?imagename=<?php echo urldecode($imagename); ?>">
    Clich here to download
</a>
```

where $imagename is the file path. And the link content can be the text or a thumbnail or whatever you want.

And just change the download.php code to get the image through $_GET and not $_POST and, important, **remove the echo that there is in there**, there should be no other content than the headers and the file content:

```
if ( isset($_GET['imagename']) ) {
    $filename = $_GET['imagename'];
    $filepath = 'images/'.$filename;
}
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($filepath));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
readfile($filepath);
```

You will not be redirected to the file and the file will be downloaded. No need of ajax for this.

In case you really prefer using javascript you could create the link dinamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modalimage").click(function(){
        var imgname = $("#downloadimg").val();
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = name;
        link.href = 'download.php?imagename=' + encodeURI(imgname);
        link.click();
    });
})
```

Comment: i have used the anchor tag... but when i used t first time it redirects to download.php is it becuase of the echo $filepath which i forgot to remove..? i'll figure it out. But Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, the echo was before any header was sent and as the headers for downloading were not there the url was redirected. No problem, I'm glad I could help.